# How to change the Vertical Scroll Bar of the UIScrollview to left site?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scrollbar

Always Vertical Scroll Bar in UIScrollBar appears in the Right Side of the ScrollView. How to change that to in left side of the UIScrollView?

Comment: and same duplicate as the answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible like this..

```
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,scrollView.bounds.size.width-8);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way. You can do it by below way.

- Iterate all the subviews of scroll view.
- Check whether the current subview is a image view or not.
- If image view is found, check for its frame.
- Check the Y co-ordinate of the image view's frame and Y co-ordinate of scrollview's frame.
- If both are equal change image view frame's x co-ordinate to 0.

Comment: Let me know. Suppose there is a external image view on scrollview with the same y coordinate then how will i find it... ?

Comment: You can tag the imageview which is added by you. Ignore the images which is having your tag.